I need assistance with a Numbervalue displaying on a part ,with a Textlabel, with it smoothly going up and down
I have tried this , here is my code
local NumberValue = workspace.Core.Ball.Value 

if workspace.Core.Ball.Value >= 100 then
    script.Parent.Text = "Temp:"..NumberValue.."Stable"
end

I was expecting it to work, but I am dumb for some coding,
I tried to take different little changes, and this is hoe far i have gotten.

Can you show the ideal result that you want to get?

You are only updating the value ONCE, I highly recommend you look into events but for now we will use the propertychangedsignal for this purpose.
I also believe you are making the grave mistake of using a numbervalue, instead of intvalue: Since the number value cannot be set/incremented to another value. So if you are change that to an intvalue too.
I also took note that you did made a nice variable called "NumberValue" but didnt used it. Which I believe you should as it makes your code much more cleaner.
local NumberValue = workspace.Core.Ball.Value 

NumberValue:GetPropertyChangedSignal("Value"):Connect(function()
    if NumberValue >= 100 then
        script.Parent.Text = "Temp:"..NumberValue.."Stable"
    end
    
end)
    

